# Alarm not working (android) interval_day

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am trying to create two alarms, one that starts my service at 7:00 p.m every day, and one that stop it at 5:00 a.m. every day. I have tested my alarm over and over and it seems interval_day does not seem to work. If I replace `AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY` with `60*1000` the alarm goes off, but with `AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY` it does not go off. I have the other alarm which uses the same code and `AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY` works with it. Any idea why that one works and the other one doesn't? How would I fix this?

EDIT: It turns out that both alarms are not working at the same time, either one or the other turns on or none at all. Is there something wrong with my code for having two alarms? Can I have only one alarm at a time? Changing the interval to 60 seconds seems to make that alarm go off 100%, but otherwise it seems they go off only 30% of the time and never both. I have no clue what might be causing this.

```
 //code that does not go off and doesnt work

 public void setAlarm(){
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DrawOverAppsService.class);
    Float alpha2 = alpha.getProgress()/100f;
    intent.putExtra("alpha", alpha2);

    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
    if(start.isChecked()) {
        alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
        java.util.Calendar calendar = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
        Log.d("a","b");
    }
    if(start.isChecked() == false) {
        alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
    }
}
//code that goes off and works

public void stopAlarm(){
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, stopOverlay.class);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
    if(stop.isChecked()) {
        alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
        java.util.Calendar calendar = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
    }
    if(stop.isChecked() == false) {
        alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: '60*1000' = 1 minute. For one day you need to calculate 60*60*24*1000

Comment: @Milos Lulic I understand that and I have tried that too. What I was asking is why is the alarm not going off when I have it set to a one day interval? And then why does it go off when it is set to one minute?